# how to handle read errors in pyarrow read_csv

Tags: pyarrow

I'm trying out apache arrow but getting a row column count error. How can I skip these rows please? In Pandas it's pretty easy but I can't see how to do the same thing in pyarrow. I just want to skip the problem rows.

```
from pyarrow import csv

test_arrow = csv.read_csv( test_file)
```

yields.

```
ArrowInvalid                              Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[6], line 1
----> 1 test_arrow = csv.read_csv( core_test_file)

File ~/Desktop/tont_24/data/spasm_1/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyarrow/_csv.pyx:1261, in pyarrow._csv.read_csv()

File ~/Desktop/tont_24/data/spasm_1/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyarrow/_csv.pyx:1270, in pyarrow._csv.read_csv()

File ~/Desktop/tont_24/data/spasm_1/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyarrow/error.pxi:154, in pyarrow.lib.pyarrow_internal_check_status()

File ~/Desktop/tont_24/data/spasm_1/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyarrow/error.pxi:91, in pyarrow.lib.check_status()

ArrowInvalid: CSV parse error: Expected 340 columns, got 679: rtee,2024-01-02,0,10.89,10.89,408,46,1409,5,11460,43.73,37.693,83.51,50.68,43.89,58.05,103.217,6 ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can skip rows with errors using the `parse_options` argument in `csv.read_csv`:

```py
from pyarrow import csv

def skip_comment(row):
    if row.text.startswith("# "):
        return 'skip'
    else:
        return 'error'

parse_options = csv.ParseOptions(invalid_row_handler=skip_comment)
test_arrow = csv.read_csv(test_file, parse_options=parse_options)
```

This example is taken from [pyarrow documentation](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.csv.ParseOptions.html#pyarrow.csv.ParseOptions)

Comment: thank you. I'll try that. I missed that in the docs ( sorry) but does that result in an arrow dataframe?   I don't see how it enables the pyarrow engine. I want to take advantage of all the new efficiencies that Arrow gets me.

Comment: The output of `read_csv` is a `pyarrow.Table` which has all Arrow advantages regarding data format, memory footprint... See https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/data.html

Comment: once AGAIN a failure to RTFM! sorry jack. I'll get to read most of the docs this weekend. Thanks again for your help and patience